# Blind deconvolution implementation, Python, Shalvi-Weinstein

Tags: python, blind-deconvolution, reference-implementation

I'd like a 1D blind deconvolution implementation in Python. I read [Shalvi and Weinstein 1990](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/18.52478) (on [the recommendation of Yair Weiss](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/old-and-new-algorithm-for-blind.html)) and it appears relatively simple.

However I can't find an existing implementation online, and I'd rather trust an established library rather than apply it directly - there may be implementation gotchas. Also, if there are no implementations online, does this mean it is not a recommended method currently?

Thus I'd like to know if this kurtosis-based algorithm is recommended by current practitioners for blind deconvolution, and if so whether there is any existing implementation I can rely on.

Comment: Kurtosis is a form of norm ratio. If you dare to try something else, you can try SOOT. A Matlab implementation is on https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50481-soot-l1-l2-norm-ratio-sparse-blind-deconvolution If you reprogram it in Python, great, let me know